# What is the technical name of the items set within an html element's style attribute?

Tags: html, css

E.g. what is the technical term for the parts of `width: 100px` within the following style attribute?

```
<div style="width: 100px;"> ... </div>
```

Is 'width' here one of the style attribute's **properties**? And then what is the technical term for the '100px' bit here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#declaration).

A *declaration* consists of a *property name*, followed by a colon, followed by a *property value* (colloquially, these are often shortened to *property* and *value*).

The particular type of property value is defined on a per-property basis. For [width](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-width-property) the value must be a *length*, *percentage*, or *auto*. You are using a [length](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-length) which consists of a *number* followed by a *unit identifier*.

Answer (score 0):

`property value`

its just the css syntax without the selector

reference: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_syntax.htm

Answer (score -1):

style is a special attribute that allows css style inline
width is a property (css property)
and 100px is its value

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_styles.asp